# What would be the Drupal way to have a preloader overlay divs untill they were finished loading?

Tags: 7, theming, javascript

I am trying to get a theme to have a pre-loader image run over each section of the theme until the corresponding div section is finished loading.

I am trying to refrain from a $(window).load(function()); if i can.

What would be the best approach?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of content are you loading? Static Images or ajax content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it can help: [queryloader2](http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader2-preload-your-images-with-ease/)

Comment: Link is dead. Never Post just links

Comment: So another link then  https://github.com/Gaya/queryloader2/